# Jade Variable is class next time?

Tags: pug

i want work more in Jade, and i have one little question.

I followed [instruction](https://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/#variables) from Jade official page to crate variable, its ok.

But how can my Jade class get values from variable?

Example, why i must type (Boostrap class) **col-md-6** its too long.
(I don't talk about packages in Atom or Sublime :D )

Maybe i can type only in Jade .f-h (**F**irst**H**alf) to name for class.

I did this :

```
  - f-h = "col-md-6"
  .f-h= f-h
```

But name of my class is **f-h** not **col-md-6** .

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the class name is too long? You could do something like the following though:

```
- fh = "col-md-6"
div(class=fh)
```

Which will compile to:

```
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
```